# Python Code to get the files from remote host using Paramiko

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, ssh, paramiko

```
import paramiko
paramiko.util.log_to_file(r'D:\logs\paramico.log')
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('xxx.xxx.xx.xx', port=22, username='xxxxx', password='xxxxxx')
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('ll')
output = stdout.readlines()
print '\n'.join(output)
print output
```

This is a linux host and I want to list the files/folders present in it. But, I am getting empty list [].

Can please any one suggest me how to proceed to list the contents present in that.

Comment: The code looks fine . can you also print out the stderr.readlines() . Most probably there might be some error that you would be getting

Comment: After using stderr.readlines(), I got the output bash: ll: command not found. But in the CLI, I could see the output ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ll
total 28
drwxr-xr-x 3 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Mar 27 11:08 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 root   root   4096 Mar 27 11:03 ../
-rw------- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  120 Mar 27 11:09 .bash_history
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  220 Mar 27 11:03 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 3637 Mar 27 11:03 .bashrc
drwx------ 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Mar 27 11:05 .cache/
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  675 Mar 27 11:03 .profile

Answer (score 0):

```
import paramiko
paramiko.util.log_to_file(r'D:\logs\paramico.log')
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('xxx.xxx.xx.xx', port=22, username='xxxxx', password='xxxxxx')
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('ls -al')
output = stdout.readlines()
output1 = stderr.readlines()
print '\n'.join(output)
print output
print output1
```

As my host has hidden files, I need to use ls -al